# Creating new assets subfolder throws error

Tags: assets

right click on source > add new subfolder > dialog box asks for subfolder name > submit = "There was an error while creating the folder."

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible suggestions:

1. Are you positive that the **File System Path** of your assets source is correct?
2. Does your assets source folder have the correct **permissions** which would allow Craft to create a new subfolder?

Comment: have checked path for source, and set permissions to 755

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is old, but wanted to post this for anyone that runs into the same problem I did.

My permissions and system path were correct; however, I was able to get it working by using an "ending forward slash" where I defined the subfolder path:

e.g.

```
{slug}/
```

instead of

```
{slug}
```

Additionally, you will also want to run a "Reindex Assets" operation located in the Admin Settings.